# How to get specific attribute of html in string using php?

Tags: php, html, regex, string, attributes

I got a  string and I need to find out all the `data-id` numbers.
This is the string

```
<li data-type="mentionable" data-id="2">bla bla... 
<li data-type="mentionable" data-id="812">some test 
<li>bla bla </li>more text 
<li data-type="mentionable" data-id="282">
```

So in the end It will find me this : `2,812,282`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to find target part of string in [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

```
preg_match_all("/data-id=\"(\d+)\"/", $str, $matches);
// $matches[1] is array contain target values
echo implode(',', $matches[1]) // return 2,812,282
```

See result of code in [demo](https://3v4l.org/sslcb)

Because your string is HTML, you can use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class to parse HTML and find target attribute in document.

Comment: `Implode` would give desired output, `echo implode(',', $matches[1]);`.

Comment: @chris85 Good mention

Answer (score 3):

Use `DOMDocument` instead:

```
<?php

$data = <<<DATA
<li data-type="mentionable" data-id="2">bla bla... 
<li data-type="mentionable" data-id="812">some test 
<li>bla bla </li>more text 
<li data-type="mentionable" data-id="282">
DATA;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($data, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$ids = [];
foreach ($xpath->query("//li[@data-id]") as $item) {
    $ids[] = $item->getAttribute('data-id');
}
print_r($ids);
?>
```

---

Which gives you `2, 812, 282`, see [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/UC777t).